# Event that fires after a certain element successfully painted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, events

I have a script that fetches random images from a database, then it shows them as the page's `backgroundImage`. It has also a loader.

The question is, how can I wait for the `div`'s painting to finish before closing the loader? When `div` receive the `background` state, and finished painting, I want to close the loader.

```js
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

const Main = () => {
    const { bgKeys, defaultColor } = React.useContext(DataContext);
    const [background, setBackground] = React.useState(null);

    const fetchBackground = React.useCallback(async () => {
        if (bgKeys.length) {
            // Get random image from IndexedDB
            const rand = bgKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgKeys.length)];
            const bg = await idbAction('backgrounds', 'getOne', rand);
            setBackground(bg.image);

            // Close the loader
            loader.classList.add('loaded');
        }
    }, [bgKeys]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchBackground();
    }, [fetchBackground]);

    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }} />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to eindbaas, a fellow Redditor, and other sources I forgot where I found them, the code below works by pre-loading the image in an `img` element (since my `div` uses css and not `src`). Then after the image loads (`onload` event), it calls the `closeLoader` function that closes the loader when the image somewhat finished painting, inside [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) callbacks.

```js
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

const Main = () => {
    const { bgKeys, defaultColor } = React.useContext(DataContext);
    const [background, setBackground] = React.useState(null);

    // Close loader
    const closeLoader = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                loader.classList.add('loaded');
                console.log('loaded');
            });
        });
    };
    const fetchBackground = React.useCallback(async () => {
        if (bgKeys.length) {
            // Get random image from IndexedDB
            const rand = bgKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgKeys.length)];
            const bg = await idbAction('backgrounds', 'getOne', rand);
            setBackground(bg.image);
        }
    }, [bgKeys]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchBackground();
    }, [fetchBackground]);

    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}>
            <img
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                onLoad={closeLoader}
                src={background}
                alt="Wallpaper"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```